# RMariaDB on Databricks

Tags: r, apache-spark, azure-databricks, mariadb-connector-c

I'm trying to get R (either via a notebook or RStudio) to connect to MariaDB on Databricks Azure 10.1. However, whether I add RMariaDB in the Libraries tab of the cluster or via install.packages("RMariaDB") in RStudio I get a failure because:

```
-----------------------------[ ANTICONF ]-----------------------------
Configure could not find suitable mysql/mariadb client library. Try installing:
* deb: libmariadb-dev (Debian, Ubuntu)
* rpm: mariadb-connector-c-devel | mariadb-devel | mysql-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
* csw: mysql56_dev (Solaris)
* brew: mariadb-connector-c (OSX)
If you already have a mysql client library installed, verify that either
mariadb_config or mysql_config is on your PATH. If these are unavailable
you can also set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------[ ERROR MESSAGE ]----------------------------
<stdin>:1:10: fatal error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

python, R, and java jar files I have installed on databricks, but not C libraries. I found the ubuntu library to download to my laptop, but the 'upload library' function in databricks seems to just want jars.

Anyone have any idea how to get R to speak to MariaDB in Databricks? Alternatively, is it possible to do the query in a python cell of a notebook (I have this working) and access the data in an R cell?

thanks

Comment: Databricks supports Conda for Python packages. And Conda to some extend supports R perhaps the package you need is available via Conda?

Comment: I don't think it is the package per se, Georg. I can install it via the normal route in databricks, or in RStudio. The trouble is it seems to have a prerequisite of a c library for mariadb, and I can't work out how to install that. I have no problem with other R packages, such as sparkly, tidy verse, or xts.

Comment: Exactly and that one should be included in Conda so it should work this way

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that on Spark/Databricks is to use `spark.read.jdbc` (see [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/read.jdbc.html)) - you just need to provide JDBC URL, user name & password.

```r
sparkR.session()
jdbcUrl <- "jdbc:mysql://<host>:3306/databasename"
df <- read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, "table", user = "username", password = "password")
```

Comment: I'll try that, Alex. I do have a connection via python and JDBC working. If that returns the data in R then we are there. Thanks, I'll report back once I've tried it.

Comment: The main question is the size of the data. If it is really large you want to feed it directly to spark without any R or Python workarounds

Comment: Understood, Georg. The SQL is set to return data from just a short time period, and what I'm looking for is to take my Shiny app, which works fine locally, onto the cloud. There are dashboards in Databricks, but they are static. I'm very cognizant of memory issues.

Comment: I tried both of these suggestions (thank for the tips), but neither seem to solve the issue. I tried using Conda to instal the r-mariadb package, with a %sh cell in a notebook, but it says: '/bin/bash: conda: command not found'. Possibly this works in an ML cluster, which this isn't. read.jdbc doesn't let me specify an sql query, only a database table name, but I need to join and filter before it gets to the notebook. There is remarkably little information on R in Databricks. I think I'll go the Kubernetes route instead. Thanks guys